# Sync Multiple Office 365 Tenant's Accounts to a single AD domain

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

According to Microsoft, this is possible using Azure AD Connect. The only caveat is, that each tenant needs a seperate instance of Azure AD Connect, therefore a seperate server to run Azure AD Connect on.

We need to sync multiple tenants, so this is cost prohibitive from a licensing standpoint as we can't have a seperate VM including a windows license for each tenant.

We require consolidation of these accounts into a single directory so that we can provide LDAP for some add on services and VPN access etc.

Is it feasible / possible to achieve this using Azure AD Connect in conjunction with Docker containers on a  single Windows Server? This way, we would install Azure AD Connect in a seperate container for each tenant, ie: in theory giving us a seperate Azure AD Connect server for each tenant.

Comment: You want to sync accounts from AAD to AD? That's not what AAD Connect does though.. It only supports sync from AD to AAD.